# How do i clear multiple user inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, function

I just started learning javascript few months ago. Recently i've been struggling to make this code work, but i end up messing up everything.

i want to make the reset button to clear user inputs?

Ive done several modification, but i couldn't still make it work. i dont know where i got it wrong.

Please i'll appreciate if anyone can assist me with this.

```
        <div class=" DTRloading__form" style="display: block;">
        
  <div class="form-container">
      <div class="info">
    
     </div>
      
     
      
      <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group w-5 ">
    <label for="red">Red Phase:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control formInline" id="red" style="width: 80px">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yellow">Yellow Phase:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control formInline" id="yellow" style="width: 80px">
  </div>
          <div class="form-group">
    <label for="blue">Blue Phase:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control formInline" id="blue" style="width: 80px">
  </div>
          <div class="form-group">
    <label for="neutral">Neutral:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control formInline" id="neutral" style="width: 80px">
  </div>

</form>
      
    <label for="inputKVA" class="sr-only">DTR CAPACITY(Amp)</label>
    <input type="number" id="inputKVA" class="form-control load" placeholder="DTR CAPACITY (KVA) *" required>
  
    <button id="btnStart3" style="margin-top: 8px" class="btn btn2 btn-lg btn-primary btn-block ">Calculate</button>
  </div>
     <div class="output">
        <h5 class="b-display">DTR Full Load Current is:</h5> 
         <div id="flA" class="form-control bill"></div>
    <h5 class="b-display">The percentage Loading of this DTR is:</h5>
    <div id="outputLoading" class="form-control bill"></div>
<!--    <div id="outputSum" class="form-control bill"></div>-->
    
    <button id="btnRefresh3" class="btn btn2 btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Reset</button>
  </div>
     
    </div>
    

    
    <script>
        
        document.getElementById("btnStart3").addEventListener('click', doCalc);
        
        

        function doCalc() {
   // Assign user inputs to variables
            
   let x = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#red").value);
   let y = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#yellow").value);
   let z = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#blue").value);
   let n = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#neutral").value);
   
    const capacity = document.querySelector("#inputKVA");
    const output2 = document.querySelector("#outputLoading");
    const output3 = document.querySelector("#flA");
    const start3 = document.getElementById("btnStart3");
    const refresh3 = document.getElementById("btnRefresh3");
        
            
                
            
            
            
//   // Call the average function
   getAverage(x,y,z,n);
}

function getAverage(x,y,z,n) {
   // Calculate the average
   let average = ((((x + y + z + n) / 3) / (capacity.value * 1.391) )* 100);
   // Display result to user 
    console.log(average);
    outputLoading.innerHTML = average.toFixed(0) + "%";
    
//
}
        const capacity = document.querySelector("#inputKVA");
    function calculate(e) {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("btnStart3 clicked");
  var totalfLA = ((capacity.value * 1000) / (1.7321 * 415));
  console.log(totalfLA);
        

  flA.innerHTML = totalfLA.toFixed(1) + "A";
}   
        
    function emptyInput() {
  console.log("emptied!");
  outputKVA.innerHTML = "";
  flA.innerHTML = "";
  x.value = "";
  y.value = "";
  z.value = "";
  n.value = "";
  capacity.value = "";
  output2.value = "";
  output3.value = "";


}   
        
        
    btnStart3.addEventListener("click", calculate);
refresh3.addEventListener("click", emptyInput); 
        
        
        </script>
```

Comment: You can use `form.reset()` to revert all the inputs to their initial defaults.

Comment: Thank you, how about the output values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in html with below button type as well.

```
 <input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

If you want reset form from javascript then

```
document.getElementById("your-form-id").reset();
```

Change

```
 1. <form class="form-inline">
 2. refresh3.addEventListener("click", emptyInput);
```

to

```
 1. <form class="form-inline" id="form">
 2. document.getElementById("btnRefresh3").addEventListener("click", emptyInput); 
 3.  function emptyInput() {
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I don't know where i missed it

Comment: well half your elements are not in the form

Comment: <input type="reset" value="Reset"> This works if i move the reset button to the form container, but it only resets input values. How do i reset the output values?

Comment: @ElvinAkpan Just assign empty strings to the `innerHTML` of those elements.